# How to find opening and closing balances

Tags: r, tidyverse

Could someone please help me find `opening_bal`and `closing_bal`.
I have all the transaction aggregates that happened in the month (new/transfers/exits etc) and I also have the closing balance 
for the last month. Using this data I needed to work back.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# this is the data and closing balance detail I have
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         placement_status_type = c("opening_bal", "New", "Transfer", "Reinstated",
                                   "Suspended", "Exit", "closing_bal"),
                       sep2018 = c(NA, 97, -40, 164, -221, -170, NA),
                       oct2018 = c(NA, 96, -40, 173, -208, -208, NA),
                       nov2018 = c(NA, 101, -36, 162, -206, -158, NA),
                       dec2018 = c(NA, 76, -27, 146, -128, -143, NA),
                       jan2019 = c(NA, 117, -23, 139, -168, -167, NA),
                       feb2019 = c(NA, 124, -39, 135, -156, -158, NA),
                       mar2019 = c(NA, 70, -18, 103, -173, -115, NA)
      )



mar2019_closing_bal <- 1000


# This is the output I am looking for
df_output <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                placement_status_type = c("opening_bal", "New", "Transfer", "Reinstated",
                                          "Suspended", "Exit", "closing_bal"),
                              sep2018 = c(1899, 97, -40, 164, -221, -170, 1729),
                              oct2018 = c(1729, 96, -40, 173, -208, -208, 1542),
                              nov2018 = c(1542, 101, -36, 162, -206, -158, 1405),
                              dec2018 = c(1405, 76, -27, 146, -128, -143, 1329),
                              jan2019 = c(1329, 117, -23, 139, -168, -167, 1227),
                              feb2019 = c(1227, 124, -39, 135, -156, -158, 1133),
                              mar2019 = c(1133, 70, -18, 103, -173, -115, 1000)
             )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without a loop using cumsum. Since you have the *final* balance and want to work backwards, we need to reverse the columns, take cumsum, subtract from the final balance and the reverse it again to get things in the original order.

```
df[1,-1] = rev(mar2019_closing_bal - cumsum(rev(colSums(df[-c(1,7),-1]))))
df[7,-1] = c(df[1,-(1:2)], mar2019_closing_bal)

df
  placement_status_type sep2018 oct2018 nov2018 dec2018 jan2019 feb2019 mar2019
1           opening_bal    1899    1729    1542    1405    1329    1227    1133
2                   New      97      96     101      76     117     124      70
3              Transfer     -40     -40     -36     -27     -23     -39     -18
4            Reinstated     164     173     162     146     139     135     103
5             Suspended    -221    -208    -206    -128    -168    -156    -173
6                  Exit    -170    -208    -158    -143    -167    -158    -115
7           closing_bal    1729    1542    1405    1329    1227    1133    1000
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a for loop, a very simple forloop which can be fairly easily coded into c++ or any language for that matter. So if you are trying to extend this to some monster of a table maybe consider that.
But for reasonable purpose this should serve well.

```
df[nrow(df), ncol(df)] <- 1000 # Just putting in the known closing balance
for(j in ncol(df):2){
  for(i in nrow(df):1){
    if (i == 1) {
      df[i, j] <- df[nrow(df), j] - sum(df[2:6, j])    
    }
    if(i == nrow(df) & is.na(df[i, j])){
      df[i, j] <- df[1, j + 1]
    }
  }
}

> df
  placement_status_type sep2018 oct2018 nov2018 dec2018 jan2019 feb2019 mar2019
1           opening_bal    1899    1729    1542    1405    1329    1227    1133
2                   New      97      96     101      76     117     124      70
3              Transfer     -40     -40     -36     -27     -23     -39     -18
4            Reinstated     164     173     162     146     139     135     103
5             Suspended    -221    -208    -206    -128    -168    -156    -173
6                  Exit    -170    -208    -158    -143    -167    -158    -115
7           closing_bal    1729    1542    1405    1329    1227    1133    1000
```